# Error running react-native run-android --variant=release (Task 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project 'gnosisapp'.)

Tags: android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm having this error trying to do `react-native run-android --variant=release`

```
Starting JS server...
Running /home/sonic182/Android/platform-tools/adb -s ZY2232QD4K reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installReleaseDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project 'gnosisapp'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.779 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

(node:24877) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

I'm over Ubuntu 16.04, I have done all the steps from here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html until the testing step where I have to do `react-native run-android --variant=release`

What could it be? :/
Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and opened an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11586

Answer (score 38):

If you are running React Native 0.39.x, please use this:

```
react-native run-android --configuration=release
```

Comment: This should be updated in the official docs...https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: There is already a PR (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11443) submitted to update the official docs.

Comment: It is documented in `react-native run-android --help`.